# How to call this function from the other function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a search form to the idea that when a user wants to search and finally press enter, then pointing to the search page they want.

HTML

```
<div class="search">        
    <form method="post" action="" onsubmit="return do_search();">
        <input type="text" value="Nhập từ khóa tìm kiếm" 
                       onfocus="if (this.value == 'Nhập từ khóa tìm kiếm') this.value = ''" 
                       onblur="if (this.value == '')this.value = 'Từ khóa'" id="searchInput" name="query" onkeydown="EnterKey(event);"/>
        <input type="submit" value="" />                            
    </form>                    
</div><!-- end #search -->
```

JS

```
function EnterKey(a) {
    if(13 == (window.event ? window.event.keyCode : a.which)){
        var temp = document.getElementById("searchInput").value;
        alert("enterkey: "+temp);
        do_search(temp);
   }
}

function do_search(a) {
     var input = document.getElementById("searchInput").value;
     alert("do_Search "+a);
     return  window.location.href = input,!1;
}
```

The problem is when I call `do_search(temp)`, the alert shows `undefined`.

Why does my alert not show the correct message?

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand what you're asking (sorry!). If you made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demonstrating the problem, it would be much easier for us to solve.

Comment: use `placeholder` for `Nhập từ khóa tìm kiếm` would be better? instead of on blur on focus?

Comment: The problem is when you `press enter key`, the form also gets submitted. So it is actually called twice that is once by pressing enter and 2nd time from `EnterKey()`.

Comment: actually you should just split your logic in 2 : 1) Treat your form whenever it is submitted, was it with enter key or click on the button 2) ensure hitting enter key submits the form, which I think is by design on all modern browsers (I know there was a trick at some point, in IE only if I remember well, if you had multiple forms or so...). And please move your event handlers out of the HTML. And if possible regarding browser support (IE10+), use `placeholder` attriburte on your input field. Actually use it and use a polyfill for browser support if needed.

Answer (score 2):

You have an error with the event onsubmit. You call the function `do_search()` without parameter. So the variable `a` is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `pressing enter` will submit the form. So it is now actually called twice, on pressing enter and calling inside `EnterKey()`. You don't have to explicitly detect `enter` then call `do_search()` as pressing `enter` will automatically call `do_search()`.